# How to enumerate files in GridFS with C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, gridfs

The GridFS api is quite simple compared to Mongo's and there are calls to read, write, stream, delete files, but I can't find any way to find the list of files, nor even how to find if a specific file exists.

I know I could keep a list of files in a table, but I am looking for a way to discover the files from scratch.

Some tools, like Studio3T are able to enumerate the files, so there is a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Find` method on `GridFSBucket` type as described [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.9/reference/gridfs/findingfiles/):

```
var bucket = new GridFSBucket(database);
var filter = Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Empty;

using (var cursor = bucket.Find(filter))
{
    var fileNames = cursor.ToList().Select(x => x.Filename);
}
```